# How change currency in paypal checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I use WooCommerce plugin in my website. When client pay via paypal on checkout page paypal shows USD dollars. Can I change the currency in paypal checkout page?

Answer (score 2):

If you [set your shop currency in WooCommerce](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/shop-currency/) it should carry over to PayPal.